# Why does my function always return undefined?

Tags: javascript

I have written a function to search in a nested object. The problem is that it returns `undefined` instead of the expected result, that is correctly logged in the console. Whats going on there?

```js
const in1 = [1, 2];
const in2 = [1, 2];

const vDOM = {
  1: {
    ref: in1,
    children: {
      2: {
        ref: in2,
        children: {}
      }
    }
  }
}

const findVDOMNode = function(instance, vDOM) {
  const keys = Object.keys(vDOM);
  const foundKey = keys.find(key => vDOM[key].ref === instance);

  //console.log(foundKey, vDOM, "FK");

  if (!keys.length) {
    console.log('no keys');
    return;
  }
  if (foundKey) {
    console.log('found', vDOM[foundKey]);
    return true; //vDOM[foundKey];
  };

  keys.map(key =>
    findVDOMNode(instance, vDOM[key].children));
}

console.log('res: ', findVDOMNode(in2, vDOM));
```

Live example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-dapzsy

Comment: In no case are you actually `return`ing the value you log into the console…

Comment: Does he have to though? Why does it work for `in1`?

Comment: @Akaino Define "work". It's rather unclear what exactly the desired outcome is.

Comment: Do you want to log true / false or the value?

Comment: @deceze I think he's trying to log `true` or `false` if a given key was found. And he tries to achieve that by recursion.

Comment: @Akaino Your guess is as good as mine.

Comment: My guess - The function name `findVDOMNode` suggests that OP needs the node, if it has to be `true/false` name should have been `hasVDOMNode`

Comment: Yes, I will return commented reference. Booleans only for debugging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `return` at the end.

```
return keys.map(key =>
    findVDOMNode(instance, vDOM[key].children));
```

You could take the values of the object and check it against the instance. If an object is found, check the object as well. For iterating use `some` with short circuit, if the instance is found.

```js
const
    in1 = [1, 2],
    in2 = [1, 2],
    vDOM = { 1: { ref: in1, children: { 2: { ref: in2, children: {} } } } },
    findVDOMNode = (instance, vDOM) => Object
        .values(vDOM)
        .some(v => v === instance
            || v && typeof v === 'object' && findVDOMNode(instance, v)
        );
  
console.log('res: ', findVDOMNode(in2, vDOM));
```

Comment: This returns an array for `in2` and `true` for `in1`. Why's that? I think it's recursion here as he's returning `true` once a key was found.

Comment: right. but map is the wrong tool here, because the result should be a boolean value ...

Comment: OP wants the object, not a boolean.  It's been unclear until recently.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you are missing a return statement on the map in the last line of the function

```js
const in1 = [1, 2];
const in2 = [1, 2];

const vDOM = {
  1: {
    ref: in1,
    children: {
      2: {
        ref: in2,
        children: {}
      }
    }
  }
}

const findVDOMNode = function(instance, vDOM) {
  const keys = Object.keys(vDOM);
  const foundKey = keys.find(key => vDOM[key].ref === instance);

  //console.log(foundKey, vDOM, "FK");

  if (!keys.length) {
    console.log('no keys');
    return;
  }
  if (foundKey) {
    console.log('found', vDOM[foundKey]);
    return true; //vDOM[foundKey];
  };
  ///added this return statement
  return keys.map(key =>
    findVDOMNode(instance, vDOM[key].children));
}

console.log('res: ', findVDOMNode(in2, vDOM));
```